# Academic word for "squabbler"

Tags: synonyms, academia

I'm looking for a word to use in an academic proposal that conveys the idea that the individuals are fighting, potentially violently, and immaturely (optional component of the meaning) and should be separated.
I found the word "squabblers" only, which isn't really suitable for academic language.

I'd be happy to receive hints (ideally British English words).

Best,
Ivo

Comment: Did you look up ["squabbler"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/squabbler) or "squabble in a thesaurus? Can you please tell us which words you discarded and why? See also: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/squabbler/synonyms

Comment: If you can accept an adjective, perhaps _contentious_.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake in trying to find a synonym here that's academic sounding.

Comment: @KDog, could you elaborate? :)

Comment: See George Orwell's rule: Never use a foreign phrase, a scientific word, or a jargon word if you can think of an everyday English equivalent.  http://www.orwell.ru/library/essays/politics/english/e_polit

Comment: @KDog the word "foreign" is derived from Latin, as are the following: "phrase",  "scientific" and "equivalent". Whereas "jargon" comes from French. There are many "foreign" words in that one simple, but silly rule you cited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***QUARREL(L)ER***
- a person who quarrel(l)s.

According to Collin's Dictionary 
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/quarrel :

Quarrel(l)

: to disagree angrily;
squabble; wrangle

: to end a friendship 
as a result of a disagreement